# Reactjs - Flask - Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, deployment

I am new to web development. I deployed a web application whose front-end and react js and the back end is Flask python.
React and Flask are hosted on the same server (I use the o2switch server).
I followed all the tutorials to make the CORS problem bother me more, but it didn't solve the problem.

Here is a snippet of my current Flask code:

`

```
from calcul import Calcul, CoefficientCM
import pandas as pd

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "http://app.prot.sc1i.un.wf", "allow_headers": "*", "expose_headers": "*"}})
run_with_ngrok(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

def options(self):
    pass


@app.route('/calcul', methods=['POST'], strict_slashes=False)
@cross_origin(origin='http://app.prot.sc1i.un.wf',headers=['Content-Type','Authorization'], supports_credentials=True)
def main():
    response = request.get_json()
```

The detailed error on chrome is as follows:
[image]
Could you tell me how to solve this CORS problem please.

Comment: CORS can [mean a lot of things](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors), usually happens to me when I'm trying to use http through an https site

Comment: Thank you @Matthias for your answer. Actually, I'm using http. Can you tell me a bit more about how you solved your problem please. Did you change the back-end and front-end url to https?

Comment: Well I solved it by changing the url from `https` to `http` haha.. but yeah if you change everything to https it might solve the error. But like I posted there could be other reasons for the error